# Oracle 11 Select statement returning wrong colum value

Tags: oracle, iis, asp-classic, oracle11g

I'm developing a website with iis, oracle 11 and classic asp there's a select statement in oracle which is not returning the actual value stored in the column. But only for an specific record the rest of the item return the stored value.

Don't have any idea what might be happening in the database. This is the form of the statemet.

```
SELECT    Item.PersonID, Item.ItemID, Item.Name, Item.StatusItem, Item.Use,  
          Item.Reg, Description,Item.Envelope, Item.Toxic, Item.Syntoms, Items.ShortDesc, Item.GroupID,  Item.Document, Item.Comments, Item.DivisionID, Item.Material, Item.Size, Producto.Alimento, Item.REG_DATE, ITem.HTMPERSON, PICTURE, Item.Characteristic, 
Deal.DealID, Deal, Item.Novelty, Item.NoveltyType, Item.PaymentStatus, Item.TypeId,  
UPDATEDATE 

FROM  DATABASE.Item, Database.Novelty 
WHERE  Item.ItemID = 28660
AND Item.NoveltyID = Novelty.NoveltyID (+)
```

The actual problem is with the UPDATEDATE field, in the table the value stored is 18/02/2014 but in the asp web page the value reported for this field is 15/10/2012

Don't have any idea what could be wrong and how to fix it.

Greetins

Comment: You might be just referring a wrong column or table.

Comment: Are you sure you're connected to the same DB? Have you just updated that value, and not committed the change? Are you actually executing the query, or might you be looking at a cached value (held by your application code)?

Comment: I have already run the query on DBMS and the value returned id the correct one 18/02/2014, it's when I run the asp page the value is incorrect and this only happens with an specific registry as of right have not detected this error in other registries.

Comment: I meant are you sure it's running now in ASP and isn't cached there? How do you know which is correct - have you just updated it in the session where you are running the query manually? If so did you commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re populated the table and the record was just read correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the transaction that updated the UPDATEDATE field in didn't commit. In this case you would still get the old value back in other sessions, but the new value in the same session you updated the value with.

Comment: I was able to look the update date in deifferent sessions but when the web page read the value has another date. Well I re populated the whole table and now is working fine.